# Monitor Not Operating Properly In Wayland

Tags: linux, graphics-card, resolution, xorg, wayland

I have three monitors. Two of them work perfectly. One is an older Asus monitor, and the other, which is particularly interesting for this question (because it works perfectly and is a similar model to the one that isn't- also made by the same manufacturer), is an Acer XFA240.

The monitor that is having difficulty is an XB240H. It seems to have the same issue when using X.org. For example, in X.org, I have attempted using xrandr in conjunction with cvt to create a custom resolution. (1080x1920, in this case, at 144Hz) Applying the resolution does nothing. Arandr has been able to list the screen in its graphical user interface, but I am unable to have it list anything other than custom resolutions (which, as stated, do not work) and 640x480.

In Wayland, the monitor shows up in the GNOME Settings menu, but I cannot change the resolution. I suspect this is an issue with EDIDs or something, but I am afraid to get my hands too dirty.

I am running Fedora 35 with the Linux kernel of version 5.15.17-200.fc35.x86_64. I have not made any modifications to the kernel. I primarily use Wayland, and although I would prefer my monitor to work in both, I do not expect to be switching back and forth, so getting it to work in Wayland is all that I am really concerned about.

I am willing to provide any specifications you need, at request. (I don't store my credit card info on my PC. lol.)

Edit: I am using GDM and GNOME's desktop environment.

Editra: The monitor displays at the maximum, 16:9 resolution during POST, but gives me 640x480, non-negotiable, at GDM. My motherboard is an Asus Prime Z390-A and my graphics card is an MSI Radeon RX 580.

Editraga: GRUB seems to display a resolution slightly higher than 640x480.

Edit-004: Windows 10/11 allows me to use 1920x1080 at 144Hz. It used to allow me to change it to 144Hz from the settings menu, but that was a few months ago when I was using the Dev version from the Windows Insider Program. As of today, I have to go to the device properties page to change it to 144Hz, whereas the settings application only accepts 60Hz as an option. Windows also identifies the monitor as an XFA240HA, which is- again- quite strange from my perspective.

Edit-005: I have tried switching the cables and the input locations on the graphics card to no avail. Now that I look at it, the settings menu integrated into the monitor itself lists the max refresh rate as 60Hz, but it also lists the resolution as 640x480, which suggests that these details are relative to the currently used settings.

Edit-006: I just ran into this "[drm:dc_link_detect_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* No EDID read." in my dmesg logs today. I am going to try to search around for how to fix this.

Edit-007: This issue has persisted from (around) 5.15.6 to 5.16.16. It really seems to be a kernel issue. Is there nothing that can be done?

Edit-008: The issue is still around on 5.17....

Comment: I highly recommend you report this at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with MSI for updated drivers, or alternatively rolled back to a previous driver? Odd things like this almost always come back to limitations or problems with the drivers although I think that card had some QC problems as well. It sounds like you've ruled out most possibilities so aside from the drivers, I hate to be the one to say it, but you may need to replace the graphics card.

Comment: The only driver I have ever known to work with amd gpus on Linux is the one titled "amdgpu", sadly. I, technically, cannot rule out several issues, still (such as with EDID, for instance.) since the card worked fine in Windows a year ago and is- at least- capable of rendering two other monitors perfectly fine in both Linux and Windows.